# Intellij IDEA Inspection Ignores Config Folder

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle based Spring Boot application which requires an external properties file.  Fortunately, Spring Boot automatically looks for an application.properties file in a /config folder by default, so I put that in the module root and it works fine.  However, it seems that IDEA's inspection is marking everything in this file as "Unused Property".  If I move the file to /src/main/resources the inspections work properly.

So, what is the best practice when working with these external properties files?  Is there something I can set in the build.gradle to get IDEA to recognize the properties or some setting in IDEA?  I've tried playing around with the Spring Facets in the project settings, but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!